# How to get array data within particular indexes in django-rest-framework

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

Suppose I have array data stored in my Postgres, such as

```
 "citations": [
        "82",
        "60",
        "53",
        "45",
        "43",
        "41",
        "41",
        "33",
        "28",
        "27",
        "25",
        "23",
        "20",
        "19",
        "17",
        "16",
        "15",
        "15"]
```

Can I access elements within certain indexes from the `citations` array through a GET request? For example, a (hypothetical) query such as `http://127.0.0.1:8000/users?query=citations?start_index=0?end_index=4` would return the elements `82,60,53,45,43` ? This would help me for creating an infinite scrolling for my JavaScript front-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override the `get_queryset` method of your ModelViewSet. In that method you can access the GET parameters and filter the queryset based on those.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = your_queryset
    if self.request.GET.get('start_index', '') and self.request.GET.get('end_index', ''):
        start_index = self.request.GET.get('start_index', '')
        end_index = self.request.GET.get('end_index', '')
        return queryset.values_list('citations', flat=True)[start_index:end_index]
    else:
        return queryset
```